# Code to Text (PHP, languages)

Tags: php, ajax, utf-8

When I submit a post with AJAX that is not in English, I will get something similar to `%u4F60%u662F%u5982%u4F55%u505A%uFF1F`
What can I do to fix this in PHP? I've tried `utf8_decode` and doesn't work.

I'm submitting the text with AJAX if that helps.

Comment: What's the characterset defined as in the output document?  You may need to change it.

Comment: I'm using `iso-8859-1`. And Lol, I wasn't thinking when I posted that, whoops

Comment: `$thing=new Thing;$thing->do_some_stuff();`

Comment: um no, that is not my code :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
<?php

  function utf8_urldecode ($str) {
    return urldecode(preg_replace_callback('/%u([0-9A-F]{4,6})/i', function($matches) {
      $int = hexdec($matches[1]);
      switch (TRUE) {
        case $int < 0x80:
          return pack('C*', $int & 0x7F);
        case $int < 0x0800:
          return pack('C*', (($int & 0x07C0) >> 6) | 0xC0, ($int & 0x3F) | 0x80);
        case $int < 0x010000:
          return pack('C*', (($int & 0xF000) >> 12) | 0xE0, (($int & 0x0FC0) >> 6) | 0x80, ($int & 0x3F) | 0x80);
        case $int < 0x110000:
          return pack('C*', (($int & 0x1C0000) >> 18) | 0xF0, (($int & 0x03F000) >> 12) | 0x80, (($int & 0x0FC0) >> 6) | 0x80, ($int & 0x3F) | 0x80);
        default:
          return $matches[0];
      }
    }, $str));
  }

  $str = "%u4F60%u662F%u5982%u4F55%u505A%uFF1F";

  echo utf8_urldecode($str);
```

I have never tried to convert hex UTF-8 code points to binary before, turns out it's actually quite easy when you get your head around it. Of course, it may still display as nonsense in your browser, depending on what the characters actually are - you may need install a language pack for them to render correctly.