# PHP convert preg_replace to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php

Just wondering how I can convert the following `preg_replace()` to `preg_replace_callback()` - I am having difficulty converting to `preg_replace_callback()` as `preg_replace()` is been deprecated.

```
$tableData['query'] = preg_replace('/{%(\S+)%}/e', '$\\1', $tableData['query']);
```

Replace all `$string` with `$string` variable.

Thanks heaps in advance

Comment: From the docs - "An E_DEPRECATED level error is emitted when passing in the "\e" modifier." The function itself is not deprecated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [alternative for function preg\_replace e/ modifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895555/alternative-for-function-preg-replace-e-modifier)

Comment: @Darragh Thanks, so do i just remove it or replace with? Sorry pretty bad at regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way. I am assuming you know the dangers of `eval`, so use this at your own risk.

```
$locals = get_defined_vars();

$tableData['query'] = preg_replace_callback('/{%(\S+)%}/', function ($match) use ($locals) {
    if (!array_key_exists($match[1], $locals)) {
        // the variable wasn't defined - do your error logic here
        return '';
    }
    return $locals[$match[1]];
}, $tableData['query']);
```

Additional word of warning - any 'declared' variable is fair game! Nothing to stop me having something like this inside the `$tableData['query']` variable:

```
I am evil and want to see {%super_secret_variable%}!
```